# How to switch between an app's windows using the keyboard on Leopard?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-leopard

How to switch between an app's windows using the keyboard on Leopard?

You can to cmd+tab to switch app, but isn't there a way to do the same thing within a single app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually Command-` (that's Command + backquote).